# Android Saripaar issue with fragments (DialogFragment)

Tags: android, validation, saripaar

I have used Saripaar successfully within activities, but now, when I use it with `DialogFragment`, it always go to `onSuccess` even in wrong input as well.

My `Fragment` is implementing `ValidationListener` and `Validator` is initialized in `onCreate()` of `Fragment` as well.

Does anyone has idea about its behaviour in fragments..???

---

Here is my code over view...

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements ValidationListener {
    // Declaring validator
    private Validator validator;

    // views to validate
    @Required(order = 1)
    @TextRule(order = 5, minLength = 6, message = "Enter at least 6 characters.")
    private EditText nameEditText;

    @Required(order = 2)
    private EditText addressEditText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Initializing validation process
        validator = new Validator(getActivity()); /*====*/
        validator.setValidationListener(this);
    }

    positiveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // Validating on positive button event
                validator.validate();
            }
        });
    }

    // Here are the validation listener methods to implemented
    // Just copy pasted from you github account tutorial page
}
```

Every thing seems right...onSuccess event is invoking perfectly everytime...Don't know what is the issue actually, or where im doing something wrong...

One thing i suspect is, call to `getActivity()` in line `validator = new Validator(getActivity());` might cause issue, like your implementation is depending on context of activity, and in dialog fragment, we are out of context some what...well, you can guess it better...:)

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
validator = new Validator(this); /*====*/
```

instead of

```
validator = new Validator(getActivity()); /*====*/
```

Also, please use the latest source. The jar is a bit outdated. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: im using the latest jar of (11242012) found at github account...and i tried to pass 'this' as well, but compiler says "The constructer Validater(MyDialogFragment) is undefiend.". I casted MyDialogFragment to Fragment as well but no gain. I can see constructor with Activity and Fragment as well, but its not accepting DialogFragment...

Comment: The latest jar is outdated. Please use the source. I'll upload a jar when I can.

Answer (score -1):

Add an additional "if" to ask if the "controller" was of the type "support" fragment, in cases where the "native fragment" is not used, doing this it is possible to do the validations also in this class fragment

here my Validator.java

```
 public Validator(final Object controller) {
        assertNotNull(controller, "controller");
        ...

        else if(controller instanceof android.support.v4.app.Fragment){
            Activity activity = (Activity) ((android.support.v4.app.Fragment) controller).getContext();
            mValidationContext = new ValidationContext(activity);
        }

    }
```

**update**

now no change is necessary to support android.support.v4.app.Fragment, my pull request for change was accepted :)

[image]
[https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar/pull/205/commits/673b7ea7174848b96bce1ae82fa2118d1af9f128](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar/pull/205/commits/673b7ea7174848b96bce1ae82fa2118d1af9f128/)